# Rank of Local authenticated player in All Time best in game center leaderboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center, leaderboard

I want to get the Rank of my local players score in all time best section in game center leaderboard. I only found the code to retrieve local player's uploaded score . How to get its rank in leaderboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
GKScore* score = [leaderBoard localPlayerScore];
NSInteger rank = score.rank;
```

You should receive top scores by calling:

```
[leaderBoard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* topScores, NSError* error){
     if (!error) {
        // topScores
     }
}];
```

Comment: as u write here [leaderBoard LocalPlayerScore]; just let me know What is "leaderBoard" Here??? which type of object this is? @tornado

Comment: GKLeaderboard* leaderBoard;