# Getting position of local player on leaderboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I am writing a custom leaderboard and I just want to know given the player ID, where he/she is on the leaderboard.

I have found this thread: [Rank of Local authenticated player in All Time best in game center leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222435/rank-of-local-authenticated-player-in-all-time-best-in-game-center-leaderboard)

But I am having trouble implementing it. Here is what I have:

```
-(void) retrieveScoresForPlayers:(NSArray*)players
                        category:(NSString*)category
                           range:(NSRange)range
                     playerScope:(GKLeaderboardPlayerScope)playerScope
                       timeScope:(GKLeaderboardTimeScope)timeScope
{
    if (isGameCenterAvailable == NO)
        return;

    GKLeaderboard* leaderboard = nil;
    if ([players count] > 0)
    {
        //leaderboard = [[[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:players] autorelease];
        leaderboard = [[[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]]] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        leaderboard = [[[GKLeaderboard alloc] init] autorelease];
        leaderboard.playerScope = playerScope;
    }

    if (leaderboard != nil)
    {
        leaderboard.timeScope = timeScope;
        leaderboard.category = category;
        leaderboard.range = range;

        [leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* scores, NSError* error)
         {
             [self setLastError:error];
             //[delegate onScoresReceived:scores];
             if (_gkhDelegate != NULL) {
                 _gkhDelegate->onScoresReceived([self convertNSArrayOfGKScoresToCppVector:scores]);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Whenever I print the rank though, it is always 1 regardless of the actual number. I suspect it's returning the rank in the query. How do I return the abolute position in the leaderboard?

Comment: I don't see where you're getting the rank, I only see where you're getting the list of scores.

Comment: @AdamPro13 What would be the correct way to go about doing this? I figured that it was done automatically when they re passed to the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after you receive the scores, it is calling the `onScoresReceived` delegate method and passing in the vector of scores.

You will want to implement that delegate method so you can take the vector of scores & sort the objects by score if needed (not sure if they'll already be sorted). Each `GKScore` has a `player` property that you should be able to compare & see if that player matches your local player.